# Replacing composite key for optimizing performance

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am using mariadb and My sql for different version.I have a table ShellInfo with field ShellID,AuthID,ShellDate,Command.Here the table has composite key to ensure unique record.If the data is huge insertion is taking too much time.

Is there suitable replacement for composite key.

Comment: Are INSERTs likely to continue to be the most common SQL operation on this table?

Comment: @Strawberry yes.We are parsing huge files(audit info) and inserting the records in to db.

Comment: So switching from (presumably) InnoDB to MyISAM would help.

Comment: @Strawberry I want to remove composite key.I need alternate strategy to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: As I understood it, you wanted to improve performance.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes I want to improve the performance.I am testing InnoDB to MyISAM option.I also want to know is there any other approach other than composite key to ensure uniqueness of data and performance benefit.

Comment: If the requirement is that the composite values are UNIQUE, then I cannot see how replacing them with something else is going to make sense - regardless of any performance benefit!?!?